# What Anime is this about a Female Arms Dealer with a bodyguard who hates her?

Tags: jormungand

I remember seeing this on an online store but I can't remember the name. I know that it's has 2 Seasons and I know it was released in the US but I not 100% sure who has the licenses, for some reason I get the feeling it was Funimation. I remember seeing it as a new release so it's somewhat recent, 2010's.

The 2 characters I remember is a Female who I seem to remember wearing white and has long white/silver hair. she works as an Arms Dealer and is well known for being ruthless but none the less successful.

She has a bunch of bodyguards but one in particular is a youngish boy who hates her because she's an arms dealer. I get the feeling he's a child solider and may be middle eastern because he has darker skin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is [Jormungand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jormungand_%28manga%29)

> The series follows Koko Hekmatyar, a young arms dealer who sells weapons under HCLI, an international shipping corporation and illegal smuggling operation. As one of the company's unofficial weapon dealers, she sells weapons in a variety of countries while avoiding both local and international authorities. Traveling with her is a team of bodyguards, mostly composed of former soldiers. Her latest addition to her crew is Jonah, an inexpressive and deadly child soldier who hates arms dealers.

As you can see from the Wikipedia Link Funimation licensed both season and the original run for the first season was in 2012.

The female you describe is Koko who is the arms dealer while the boy is Jonah which in the quote above (taken from Wikipedia) is a child solider who hates arms dealers.

This image bellow also also shows Koko and Jonah. Koko is in the middle with the white miniskirt and Johan is at the right end with the dark skin

[image: Cast]

and the cover of the manga on Wikipedia (can't post a second link) shows Koko, while wearing a black skirt wears a white coat which is like a trademark of hers.

Comment: Oh my god thank you this is it, thank you : )